# Functions that checks the same characters in field

Tags: arrays, c

Hello how to make a function return true if all the characters in the columns are the same? I edit this post.. Thank you for your response.

She could look like this?
Is it possible to change it?

```
for(int i =0; i <  rows; i++){
   for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++){
       if(field[i][j] == field[i][j]){
         return true;
        }
        else{
         return false;
        }

     }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use correct type for sizes (`size_t`)
2. you need to decide if rows or cols are zero if it should return `true` or `false`.

```
bool check(const size_t rows, const size_t columns, const char field[rows][columns])
{
    //if(!field) return false;
    //if(!rows || !columns) return false;
    for(size_t row = 1; row < rows; row++)
        for(size_t col =  0; col < columns; col++)
            if(field[row][col] != field[0][col]) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank, you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

the function needs to return false as soon as it notices the difference.

```
for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
   for(int j = 1; j < columns; j++)
       if(field[0][i] != field[j][i])
         return false;
return true;
```

Comment: int is a wrong type for sizes and indexes

Comment: oh, thanks, I'll get used to using unsigned variables for such purposes

Comment: Thank  your very much :)

Comment: `[0]` -> `[j]` is a typo, right? It is more cache-friendly if you invert the loops.

Comment: no, that's not a typo. I didn't understand 0___________'s answer at all. the algorithm must compare the elements of each column, not rows. You can see the original version of the question. It will become much clearer. Either I'm terribly dumb. 0_0